# Counter stored in .txt file not incrementing

Tags: php, html, counter, file-access

So I've just now edited the Code I've posted to make it much nicer to read...
This first block of code is my Counter Code used for the hits on a succesfull submition button. But for some reason the value of $Total will not increase by 1 even tho it was a succesfull submition.

```
<?php 
  $f = fopen('count.txt', 'r+'); // use 'r+' instead
  $total = fgets ($f);
  flock($f, LOCK_EX); // avoid race conditions with concurrent requests
  $total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('count.txt'))); // arg can't be 0
  /*if someone has clicked submit*/
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    rewind($f); // move pointer to start of file so we overwrite instead of append
    fwrite($f, ++$total);
  }
  fclose($f);
?>
```

And here is the submition button which I'm using to submit my form.

```
<input type="reset" value="Formular löschen" style="width:49%" />  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Formular absenden" style="width:49%" />
```

Im trying to use this coed for my Club so that when the People submit the form they get the number as a refference Number also sent to them in the email sent.

I really hope thet there is a eays way of doing this without a DB.

Mark

If you want to see what i mean what the problem is, [here](http://www.acherner-bogenclub.de/contakt1.php) is the page with the code impelemented.

Comment: the Website im working on at the Moment is http://www.acherner-bogenclub.de/contakt1.php if you would want to see what i mean

Comment: Please try to reduce the amount of code or make it more readable

Comment: @asur how do i do that coz im new here? I thought showing all of the php script is important...

Comment: Is a good practice, for example to post logic and mark up separated, with a good indentation and debug data. If you do so you make easier for people to answer your question :)

Comment: @Asur thanks for the tip. I will do this then the next time. :D do u maybe know whats wrong with my Code?

Comment: The only thing I've found in a quick check is already answered so...

Comment: @asur is this better now? :D

Comment: Hello, I've checked your code, and I'm making a simple approach to guide you, I'll post it in answers soon ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a couple of tips you may find useful when you are manipulating files:

- You have to always check the files and folders permissions, just to make sure.
- Be careful with multi-thread code, you may get really unexpected results when several threads are changing a file at the same time, so try to control that using locks, as you did.

I think you missed you `<form>` tag, so I had to invent my own one. 
Use this code as a guide to make your own one:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>  

<?php 
  // Thread-safe <-- Use me
  function incrementFile ($file){
    $f = fopen($file, "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    // We get the exclusive lock
    if (flock($f, LOCK_EX)) { 
      $counter = (int) fgets ($f); // Gets the value of the counter
      rewind($f); // Moves pointer to the beginning
      fwrite($f, ++$counter); // Increments the variable and overwrites it
      fclose($f); // Closes the file
      flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // Unlocks the file for other uses
    }
  }

  // NO Thread-safe
  function incrementFileSimplified ($file){
    $counter=file_get_contents('count.txt');
    $counter++;
    file_put_contents('count.txt', $counter);
  }

  // Catches the submit
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     incrementFile("count.txt");
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps you! :)

Comment: Thank you verry much now it is counting atleast the number of submitions but im stuck with getting it into the email which is being set from the form.

Comment: Welcome, the email is a different question, first try to do it your self and if after tried hard you just can't make it work post a new question, if the answer clarified your problem just tick it so people can find it and solve a similar situation :)

Comment: Again welcome and remember, it's perfectly fine to ask, but always research first for similar answers, and if your case is different, post it in a correct format to make easier for people to help you. Greetings ;)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you never set `$total` before writing it to the file.
You need to set `$total` by reading its value from the file, like this:
`$total = fgets ($f)`  right after `fopen` function call.

However, you may have troubles with concurrency without exclusive file lock so you may lose some submissions count.